# How to create Box<Box<dyn Trait>>, and turn it into Box<Box<T>>

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I'm implementing a Windows API application in Rust. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a very simple windows procedure, with a minimum code needed to route incoming window messages to appropriate windows, so every window implementation can have its own message processing. The window procedure is common to all windows I have in my application.

```
extern "system" fn wndproc(window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        if message == WM_CREATE {
            let create_struct = lparam.0 as *const CREATESTRUCTA;
            let app_window = (*create_struct).lpCreateParams as *mut Box<dyn AppWindow>;

            SetWindowLongPtrA(window, WINDOW_EXTRAS_MAIN, app_window as isize);

            (*app_window).handle_create((*create_struct).hInstance, window, message, wparam, lparam)
        } else {
            let app_window =
                GetWindowLongPtrA(window, WINDOW_EXTRAS_MAIN) as *mut Box<dyn AppWindow>;

            // Some messages could be sent before the window is instantiated, so route them to the
            // default procedure.
            if !app_window.is_null() {
                (*app_window).process_message(window, message, wparam, lparam)
            } else {
                DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I receive `WM_CREATE` I'm extracting a `Box` with with my `dyn AppWindow` trait inside. Every window implementation in my application implements this trait, so I can leverage the polymorphic behavior here, and call methods on the implementations without knowing the exact window.

I'm also storing a pointer to the boxed trait in window's memory, so when I receive messages other than `WM_CREATE` I can extract the pointer, and call `process_message` on the target window.

Here's my `AppWindow` trait, it's very simple:

```
pub trait AppWindow {
    fn handle_create(&mut self, app_instance: HINSTANCE, window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT;
    fn process_message(&self, window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT;
}
```

Below you can find a code of a `new` method for one of the window implementations.

```
impl AppWindow for ControlCenter {
    // ...
}

impl ControlCenter {
    pub fn new(instance: HINSTANCE) -> Box<Box<ControlCenter>> {
        let cc: Box<Box<dyn AppWindow>> = Box::new(Box::new(ControlCenter::default()));

        unsafe {
            CreateWindowExA(
                WINDOW_EX_STYLE::default(),
                WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,
                s!(""),
                WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME,
                0, 0, 300, 200,
                HWND::default(),
                None,
                instance,
                Some(&*cc as *const Box<dyn AppWindow> as *const c_void)
            );
        }

        cc // Problem is here
    }
    
    pub fn show_window(&self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm creating a double-box with a dyn trait inside, so the outer box puts the inner box on a heap, and the inner box can wrap a fat pointer of the trait. The heap address of the inner box is given to `lpCreateParams` of `CreateWindowExA`, and that's how it finds its way to the window procedure you've seen earlier.

## The Question

It's rather obvious I can't simply return `cc` because it doesn't match the function's signature, but I really want the function to return the concrete type, not the trait. The reason is that the only place in the application where I need a polymorphic behavior is the window procedure, so I can easily route the messages. Elsewhere in the code I'm going to communicate with the window instances directly, and I don't care about polymorphism. For example:

```
let control_center = ControlCenter::new(app_instance);
control_center.show_window();
```

I've tried different methods, I've tried looking for code samples, questions on SO, questions on other boards, but I couldn't find any clue. The general idea of storing the boxed trait in window's memory works; I can call `handle_create` and `process_message` on instances properly. I was able to do so when I obeyed and returned `Box<Box<dyn AppWindow>>` from the function, but I don't want it that way.

Comment: The bad news: you cannot do _exactly_ that. The good news: you can do some close things.

Comment: You have undefined behavior: you're creating a mutable reference from an immutable reference.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What will be the closest solution? I know the code is not perfect, it's a mess right now because while looking for a solution I'm doing thousand things at the same time, and constantly changing implementation.

Comment: You are making the problem appear a lot easier than it is. Writing a user-extensible windowing framework is a fair bit more involved. To my knowledge, [`win-win`](https://github.com/raphlinus/win-win) is the only crate that gets the lifetimes right, across all invisible code paths (which all other crates, including the approach here, simply ignore).

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, that's very probable. Though I already wrote a couple of programs using Windows API, I'm rather new in Rust. Sometimes I'm trying to do things that are perfectly fine in C, but are not so straightforward in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `Box<Box<dyn Trait>>` turned into `Box<Box<T>>` because the size of `Box<dyn Trait>` is two usizes while the size of `Box<T>` is one usize, so you need to turn an allocation of two usizes to an allocation of one usize, which means reallocation.

But you can come close: you can store the data in `Rc` instead of `Box`, then have `Box<Rc<dyn AppWindow>>` in `wndproc()`, and `Rc<ControlCenter>` in other places, both pointing to the same `Rc`. If you need mutation, you can wrap them in `RefCell` (`Box<Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>>` and `Rc<RefCell<ControlCenter>>`). You likely need that anyway to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm closer to the solution now. The last thing that I'm wrapping my head around is preventing that `Box<Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>>` from being moved out from the `new` function. I have these variables: `let rced = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ControlCenter::default())); let boxed = Box::new(Rc::clone(&rced) as Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>);`. To `CreateWindowEx` I'm passing: `&*boxed as *const Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>> as *const c_void`. From the `new` I return `rced`. I think I can return a tuple with both variables, so the `boxed` isn't destroyed, but maybe there's a better option.

Comment: @itachi [`Box::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) is the solution.

Comment: That was my first idea, thanks for confirming :). I will post the solution later, maybe someone will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chayim Friedman's assistance I was able to achieve my goal. For completeness I'm attaching code snippets presenting what I eventually came up with, maybe someone will find it helpful. Please keep in mind that this is an experimental approach, I didn't fully test it yet, so I can't guarantee it will work flawlessly.

The first snippet is the `new` function which creates a new window. The moment I create a raw pointer from the box is very important. The box loses a control over the cloned `Rc`, so it can be given to the window procedure without a fear the clone will be destroyed when the function returns. That also means it must be manually deallocated at some point to prevent memory leaks, and allow proper application exit.

```
pub fn new(instance: HINSTANCE) -> Rc<RefCell<ControlCenter>> {
    let my_rc = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ControlCenter::default()));
    let boxed = Box::new(Rc::clone(&my_rc) as Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>);
    let raw = Box::into_raw(boxed);

    unsafe {
        CreateWindowExA(
            WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW,
            WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,
            s!(""),
            WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
            HWND::default(),
            None,
            instance,
            Some(raw as *const Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>> as *const c_void),
        );
    }

    my_rc
}
```

The next snippet is the window procedure. In `WM_CREATE` I'm storing an address of the cloned `Rc` in window's memory, so I can later retrieve it and invoke methods on the underlying instance. The very important thing happens in `WM_NCDESTROY` arm. This message is the last message sent to a window when it's destroyed, making it a perfect place to do some cleanup actions. I'm re-creating the box, and let it be destroyed.

```
extern "system" fn wndproc(window: HWND, message: u32, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match message {
            WM_CREATE => {
                let create_struct = lparam.0 as *const CREATESTRUCTA;
                let app_window = (*create_struct).lpCreateParams
                    as *mut Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>;

                SetWindowLongPtrA(window, WINDOW_EXTRAS_MAIN, app_window as isize);

                (*app_window).borrow_mut()
                    .handle_create((*create_struct).hInstance, window, message, wparam, lparam)
            }
            WM_CLOSE => {
                DestroyWindow(window);
                LRESULT(0)
            }
            WM_NCDESTROY => {
                let app_window =
                    GetWindowLongPtrA(window, WINDOW_EXTRAS_MAIN)
                        as *mut Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>;

                if !app_window.is_null() {
                    Box::from_raw(app_window);
                    LRESULT(0)
                } else {
                    DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam)
                }
            }
            _ => {
                let app_window = GetWindowLongPtrA(window, WINDOW_EXTRAS_MAIN)
                        as *mut Rc<RefCell<dyn AppWindow>>;

                if !app_window.is_null() {
                    (*app_window).borrow().process_message(window, message, wparam, lparam)
                } else {
                    DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The window can be created by simply calling `ControlCenter::new(app_instance)`. The returned `Rc<RefCell<ControlCenter>>` can be stored for later use when there's a need to interact with the instance, or it can be completely ignored - the instance won't be dropped because it is referenced from the cloned `Rc` which lives on a heap, and will remain alive until the `WM_NCDESTROY` message for the window arrives.